# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class, have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

I am trying to start an activity from StationFragment to Dashan1Activity. Its not working and driving me nuts. What I have is:

1. error message：

   > android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
   >   activity class {com.coastline20/miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity}; have
   >   you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
2. Manifest

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.coastline20">

    <application
       ...        
       <activity android:name=".miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity" />
    </application>    
   </manifest>
   ```
3. StationFragment

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(getActivity(), "miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity");
     getActivity().startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

Comment: What does your project structure look like? There is a `/` in `com.coastline20/.miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Where is the Station Fragment declaration in Manifest file. It shows only Dashan1Activity declartion

Comment: Fragments are not declared inside Android Manifest.

Comment: I have no idea why there is a / .

Comment: Besides, I  am trying to start an activity from StationFragment to MainActivity, and there is the same problem with / .

Comment: Put StationFragment code. It may help to solve.

Comment: It solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing your package name while building the application.  So try this.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(getActivity(), Dashan1Activity.class);
  getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

you must use getActivity() for starting the activity. If you didn't use it then it will give exception because OnClickListenter class can't launch an activity.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

If you want explicit Intent only then, try this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(getActivity(), "com.coastline20.miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity");
  getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The update answer is the same as Hadi Ahmadi's comment. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching your next activity like this instead

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), new Dashan1Activity());
  getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  final Activity ac = getActivity();
  Intent intent = new Intent(ac, Dashan1Activity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

its working for me

**Update**

you have to Write The Hole Class Name.
 ".miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity" is not the hole Class name

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it's must be "setClassName()" in my project.

Comment: What is the uses of "setClassName()"?

Comment: It assign activities' name (String), not activities (class).

Comment: i dont used it till now but maybe you have to write the hole class name . 
 ".miaoli.dashan.Dashan1Activity" is not the hole activity name . hope it work

Comment: There are lots of items which intent to activities when clicking. Therefore, it need activities' name, not activities.

Comment: Thank Hadi Ahmadi for your help. It works. The whole class name is the correct answer.

Comment: Your Welcome . glad to be useful (:

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Dashan1Activity.class);
  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It's because of a bug in android studio.To solve this problem you should make a little changes in your `Run/Debug Configuration` :
set `Deploy` in `Installation Options` path to `Nothing` , compile the project and then Undo this settings. It works well for me.[image: Run/Debug Configuration]